# Is there a way to add MRU tab selection via CTRL+TAB to Google Chrome?

Tags: google-chrome

I haven't been able to find an extension or built-in way to get this functionality.

I have seen a couple of hacks on the web, but none that work properly. Eg this standalone application:

https://github.com/acemtp/chrome_mru

Comment: https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/clut-cycle-last-used-tabs/cobieddmkhhnbeldhncnfcgcaccmehgn

Comment: clut doesn't seem to support ctrl-tab.  Hint:  Opera does w/o any extensions or config changes.

Comment: See tricky solution for Windows here: https://github.com/boika/chrome-ctrl-tab

Answer (score 12):

Yes, there is a perfectly working solution.
This extension [**Tab Thumbnails Switcher**](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/tab-thumbnails-switcher/jpaiaplhepeiilhiegfnknedhjepknng) can redefine <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Tab</kbd> and <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Tab</kbd> to select tabs in MRU order the same way you swich between programs with Alt+Tab in Windows.

[image]

The best part is that the tab selector box is implemented natively, so it doesn't need to inject javascript on each tab for it to work. It works reliably on all tabs.

There's also a demonstrative video here: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=2HC7_EI8db4

Comment: Finally! and it doesn't need to manually edit some weird settings file.

Comment: Beware! Virus detected automatically by Windows 10.

Comment: Those virus detections by Windows Defender are full of false positives. To the point that Microsoft had to release an article explaining how to solve the problem: https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/883260

Comment: Only works on Windows according to its documentation.

Comment: This solution seems buggy. Ctrl+Tab switching in Visual Studio Code stopped working for me. Chrome tabs still switched, even though Visual Studio Code window had the focus.

Comment: @Marlau, haven't experienced that problem, but make sure you let the developer know about it, so they can fix it.

Comment: Also Windows only.

Comment: This requires an installation of a "Native Component" - eg you have to run an extra .exe file, which is not ideal.

Answer (score 10):

Another option I just found Yesterday (and until now it seems to work very well) is: AutoControl Shortcut Manager: https://www.autocontrol.app/switch-to-last-used-tab-in-chrome#MRU-tabs
Steps:

- Install chrome extension: [AutoControl Shortcut Manager](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/autocontrol-shortcut-mana/lkaihdpfpifdlgoapbfocpmekbokmcfd)
- Install also the required exe file: Native-Component.exe (*It will be prompted to be downloaded after the extension is installed. For me it didn't require admin rights. I hope it's ok ...*)
- Configure the extension based on the tutorial (9 steps) from the official web page: [Cycle through all tabs in MRU order](https://www.autocontrol.app/switch-to-last-used-tab-in-chrome#MRU-tabs)
- Enjoy ctrl+tab behavior :)

Comment: Only works on Windows according to its documentation.

Comment: Awesome. I was able to install this even from the Guest user account on an internet cafe.

Comment: Any option for Linux users ?

Answer (score 3):

I was able to get the [chrome_mru](https://github.com/acemtp/chrome_mru) tool working by changing the nHotKeyChar variable from 0xde to 0xc0 (from tilde ~ to tick `) and recompiling.

Then I realized this is the same thing [AutoHotkey](http://www.autohotkey.com/) does using [this script](http://pastebin.com/hpdAMSdT) with the [Recent Tabs](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/recent-tabs/ocllfmhjhfmogablefmibmjcodggknml) Chrome extension.

The AutoHotkey/Recent tabs solution is suboptimal, yes, but I think it is the best we can hope for until Chrome implements this feature (if ever /sigh).

Comment: I had to do the same thing (change from tilde to tick and recompile). Here's a link to the compiled exe for the lazy: https://www.dropbox.com/s/0l57cn18opjxir7/chrome_mru.exe

Comment: Fortunately, there's no more need for this kind of hacks. An extension called [AutoControl Shortcut Manager](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/autocontrol/lkaihdpfpifdlgoapbfocpmekbokmcfd) puts an end to our struggles. We can now customize the hell out every imaginable shortcut.

Answer (score 3):

There are two features enabled by Firefox's <kbd>ctrl</kbd><kbd>tab</kbd> shortcut that Chrome doesn't yet offer:

- **Switch to the previously used tab**

  - Press <kbd>ctrl</kbd><kbd>tab</kbd> and then release both
- **Select an open tab from a menu using the keyboard**

  - Press <kbd>ctrl</kbd><kbd>tab</kbd> but then release just <kbd>tab</kbd>
  - Press and release <kbd>tab</kbd> repeatedly to select older tabs in the menu
  - Release <kbd>ctrl</kbd> to switch to the selected tab

The only Chrome extension I know of that offers a facsimile of this — without requiring the unnecessarily broad *Read and change all your data on the websites you visit* permission and that works with tabs into which extensions can't inject code, like Chrome Webstore pages — is [QuicKey](https://fwextensions.github.io/QuicKey/) (which I wrote).

QuicKey works around Chrome's limitations by using one shortcut to open the popup menu (by default, <kbd>alt</kbd><kbd>Q</kbd> on Windows), then listening for another keypress (<kbd>W</kbd>, right next door) to move the selection in the menu, and then waiting for the <kbd>alt</kbd> `keyup` event to switch to the selected tab.

It has to use <kbd>W</kbd> instead of <kbd>Q</kbd> (which would be the equivalent to <kbd>tab</kbd> in this shortcut) because pressing that with <kbd>alt</kbd> down would close the popup. (The popup page doesn't see that key event at all so it can't block it.) But that does mean QuicKey can use a quick double-press of <kbd>alt</kbd><kbd>Q</kbd> (or double-click of the icon) as a shortcut to toggle to the previously used tab. It does that by timing how long the popup was open, and switching tabs if the time was less than 450ms.

If you want to use <kbd>ctrl</kbd><kbd>tab</kbd> as a shortcut for switching between recent tabs in QuicKey, [there's a simple, cross-platform way](https://fwextensions.github.io/QuicKey/ctrl-tab/) to do it via Chrome devtools.

Comment: I don't know why this is being downvoted, but QuicKey is a wonderful extension, so thanks!

Comment: Thanks. Awhile ago, someone went through and downvoted all the answers for some reason.

Comment: Works well, including the instructions for getting `Ctrl` + `Tab` working, but tracks you with Google Analytics and does not disclose this anywhere.

Comment: @Walf the QuicKey [privacy policy](https://fwextensions.github.io/QuicKey/privacy/) linked from the Chrome store page explains how it uses the permissions it requests and discloses the collection of anonymous diagnostic data. It doesn't mention GA by name as the mechanism for transmitting the telemetry, but it also doesn't "track" anything about the pages you're browsing.

Comment: I don't consider GA to ever be truly anonymous. Disclosing it by name would be more transparent. I did not see any use of the `anonymize_ip` feature, which migrating from UA to GA4 would resolve (the latter does not log IPs). I'm not saying you shouldn't do it, but there are better ways, and being up-front promotes trust.

Answer (score 2):

For mac users you can use this extension:
[chrome extension](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/popup-tab-switcher/cehdjppppegalmaffcdffkkpmoflfhkc)

It has a shortcut opt+y to cycle through previous tabs. And if you want to use ctrl+tab as shortcut, you can use karabiner element tool to map the opt y shortcut to ctrl tab.

the mapping i use for karabiner is like so:

```
  {
                            "from": {
                                "key_code": "tab",
                                "modifiers": {
                                    "mandatory": [
                                        "left_control"
                                    ]
                                }
                            },
                            "to": [
                                {
                                    "key_code": "y",
                                    "modifiers": [
                                        "left_option"
                                    ]
                                }
                            ],
                            "type": "basic"
                        }
```

Comment: This extension works very well for me (on Linux). The only issue is that it switches between tabs in all Chrome windows instead of limiting itself to only the tabs in the current window, and that is very confusing.

Answer (score 1):

I now found a possiblity to achieve this for users working on Windows and wrote an extension:
https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/ctrl%2Btab-mru/ialfjajikhdldpgcfglgndennidgkhik

Comment: It works, however this temporarily tab is really annoying. I hope, there will be some way to remove it at all.

Comment: You are definitely right! But as long as an extension isn't allowed to fully access any page we have to think about how to convince Google of implementing this feature directly into the browser.

Comment: This requires an installation of a "Native Component" - eg you have to run an extra .exe file, which is not ideal.

Answer (score 1):

Complete solution for setting up <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Tab</kbd> to use MRU switching on Windows:

First download an MRU extension for Chrome. After trying a few different such extensions, I recommend [Ctrl+Tab MRU](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/ctrl%2Btab-mru/ialfjajikhdldpgcfglgndennidgkhik). It's not perfect, but it's the best one I could find.

Next, you need to bind the hotkeys for your selected extension to a key combination. Go to `chrome://extensions/`, scroll down to the bottom of the page, click "Keyboard shortcuts", and find the shortcuts for the extension you selected. Unfortunately, Chrome doesn't let you bind <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Tab</kbd> as a keyboard shortcut, so instead choose a combo that Chrome *does* let you select, like <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Q</kbd> for "Switch to older tab" and <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Q</kbd> for "Switch to newer tab".

Now we need to set things up so that <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Tab</kbd> triggers the key combination you previously set. For that you'll need [AutoHotkey](https://autohotkey.com/). If you don't already have AutoHotkey, first download and install it from [its website](https://autohotkey.com/). Then, put the following text in an AutoHotkey script in your startup folder, at `%AppData%\Microsoft\Windows\Start Menu\Programs\Startup\tabswitch.ahk` (e.g. in a new text file located at `C:\Users\yourusername\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\Windows\Start Menu\Programs\Startup` and named `tabswitch.ahk`, with no `.txt` extension):

```
; Fix for Chrome's lack of MRU tab switching.
; Use this with a decent MRU tab switching extension, like
; https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/ctrl%20tab-mru/ialfjajikhdldpgcfglgndennidgkhik
; Configure it to use Ctrl-Q, or change the key below.
#IfWinActive, ahk_exe chrome.exe ; If currently using Chrome
    ^Tab::^q
    ^+Tab::^+q
#IfWinActive
```

This remaps <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Tab</kbd> and <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Tab</kbd> to <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Q</kbd> and <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Q</kbd>, respectively, when Chrome is the currently selected Window. This will allow you to use <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Tab</kbd> to switch between tabs with MRU ordering in Chrome. Don't forget to double-click the script to run it. It should start back up automatically when you reboot your computer.

Comment: I would recommend you to try 'Quick Tabs' extension. It is customizable via CSS. Also you can find ready solution here: https://github.com/boika/chrome-ctrl-tab

Comment: There is no "Keyboard shortcuts" link anymore on extensions page in Chrome.

Answer (score 0):

I am using tab stack as a workaround until Chrome has native MRU support (crossfingers) ;)
Tab Stack (https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/tab-stack/gfpdghcockbpiokcaaagmnneioeopnnb) moves the current tab to the front after a brief delay. It's very simple solution that gives you kind of MRU. 
Solutions above didn't work for me. Maybe b/c of an international keyboard layout.

Comment: Unfortunatelly this is the only working way on Macos, this is unusual so far, and very strange to see tabs changing their placements, but ctrl-tab is working and for any IT person (not grand people) this is the most important (the same as alt-tab), so let's live with this :( Very poor, that google is so irresponsive in this question.

Answer (score 0):

All ctrl-tab MRU options I have seen on Chrome feel like hacks / do not work reliably.

I recommend switching to latest [Opera](http://www.opera.com) . You basically get Chrome(ium) with a few key addings (MRU tabs, but also mouse gestures).

The setting is at opera://flags/#activation-order-tab-cycling (needs restarting the browser).

Comment: How do you enable MRU behaviour for tabs in the latest Opera?

Comment: In my version 20.0.1387.91 it works out of the box. No settings needed.

Comment: I've the same version. CTRL+TAB just loops thru all of the tabs (Chrome style) instead of switching between current and previous tab.

Comment: Right. The setting is at opera://flags/#activation-order-tab-cycling  (needs restarting the browser)

Comment: Awesome. Opera just became my default browser. Thanks a lot.

Comment: Totally bummed again. Opera 20.0 doesn't support MRU on Mac. Why devs, why would you keep this from us!! :O

Comment: Have you tried this: CLUT: Cycle Last Used Tabs. https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/clut-cycle-last-used-tabs/cobieddmkhhnbeldhncnfcgcaccmehgn?hl=en

Comment: Can confirm.  I just installed Opera on Windows 7.  It did MRU tabs using ctrl-tab without any changes to settings or plugins!  Also, I went to Facebook and didn't even need to login.  It somehow imported sessions too.  Simply amazing.

Answer (score 0):

Finally there is a working one:
https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/clut-cycle-last-used-tabs/cobieddmkhhnbeldhncnfcgcaccmehgn?hl=en

Answer (score 0):

Here's a [very light and intuitive solution](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/tab-slider/nobaaibkcalggmjnjhnlmmcldllpogjp) for tabs organizing in the most recently used order, which is supported in all major browsers (Chrome, Firefox, Opera, other Chrome-based browsers): [Tab Slider](https://github.com/ZitRos/tab-slider#tab-slider). Its features are:

- Works just like Alt+Tab on Windows or Cmd+Tab on Mac, but with browser tabs
- Visually sorts tabs so you always see them in the MRU order (Ctrl+Tab switches to the next MRU tab)
- Works with pinned tabs as well
- Is customizable (however, I would advise sticking with defaults)

Try it! Hope you'll love it.

[image: img]

Answer (score -1):

<s>Just found this https://github.com/acemtp/chrome_mru</s>

> Its goal is to enable you to use CTRL+TAB in Google Chrome with the
>   Most Recently Used (MRU) Tab behavior (and not the default
>   next/previous tab).

I didn't try it so far. Hope it helps

edit reason: Stopped working.

Comment: I now use Tab Stacker. https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/tab-stacker/opcflfmbmhilljcgiohadamajkljcimg
It has the advantage that you can use ctrl+tab. It establishes the MRU by resorting the tabs. very clever.

Answer (score -1):

Yes there is a working solution available now. I found [Recent Tabs extension](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/recent-tabs/ocllfmhjhfmogablefmibmjcodggknml) perfect for MRU tabs solution in chrome. You can use `ctrl+Q` or `ctrl+~` or assign your own.

Answer (score -1):

As an alternative I would offer using FF, in it you have to set `browser.ctrlTab.previews` setting to `true` and you have an MRU behavior.

Answer (score -1):

Better to use http://bahoom.com/hyperswitch as jason3w suggests

<s>My solution:</s>

On OSX I usually want MRU switching when I want to repeatedly switch between two chrome tabs and a code editor. (For example, trello.com and localhost:3000)

In this case, I start up chrome canary which is properly treated as a separate application by OSX, and allows for a simple alt-tabbing (like windows used to), SWEET!!

https://www.google.com/chrome/browser/canary.html

Try it out, peeps. I tried the Opera solution, but just couldn't live without some of the other features of chrome. I hope Opera continues to develop.

Comment: in this case you can use HyperSwitch http://bahoom.com/hyperswitch. Then just use 2 chrome windows. Hyperswitch in general is awesome for true MRUW (most recently used window).

Comment: Hyperswitch looks interesting, but I would rather gamble on a beta from Google, versus an unknown developer - I'll check back later when the project is more mature

Comment: been using it for years. it's solid.

Comment: So the canary solution has the problem that you get two instances of hangouts, which is really annoying.

Installed hyperswitch, looks really nice.

Answer (score -1):

> Is there a real working solution to add MRU tab selection via CTRL+TAB
>   to Google Chrome?

Yes. You need to modify Your preferences file as like here:
http://forum.ru-board.com/topic.cgi?forum=5&topic=34987&start=4680#16

(change Your sequence to Ctrl+Tab and Shift+Ctrl+Tab)

Chrome does not block it. You simply cannot assigh this combination becouse of hook.. But if You edit Preferences file, it works.

It is situated near

> "C:\Users\%username%\AppData\Local\Google\Chrome\User
>   Data\Default\Preferences"

Answer (score -1):

On Mac OS, the Recent Tabs extension is somehow able to reassign Ctrl+Tab to switch between two most recently used tabs out-of-the-box!

https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/recent-tabs/ocllfmhjhfmogablefmibmjcodggknml

Answer (score -1):

The tricky solution to achieve this on Windows is to combine [Quick Tabs](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/quick-tabs/jnjfeinjfmenlddahdjdmgpbokiacbbb) chrome extensions and [AutoHotkey](https://autohotkey.com/) script. I've described it in details [here](https://github.com/boika/chrome-ctrl-tab), so here is in a nutshell:

1) Quick Tabs is an [open-source](https://github.com/babyman/quick-tabs-chrome-extension), customizable extension, that allows you redefine some CSS styles and allows to setup hotkey for switching MRU tabs. Also it supports keyboard navigation (move to next/previous tab). However chrome doesn't let you bind <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Tab</kbd> as a keyboard shortcut, so you need to register another one (for example <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>S</kbd>) and then use AutoHotkey script to "remap" <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Tab</kbd> for chrome into <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>S</kbd>.

2) I won't put here the AutoHotkey script, you can find it [here](https://github.com/boika/chrome-ctrl-tab/blob/master/chrome-ctrl%2Btab.ahk). It covers <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Tab</kbd> remapping and handle all the keyboard navigation.

As a result you will see something like that when press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Tab</kbd> in active chrome window:

[image]

Arrows navigation, <kbd>Esc</kbd>, both <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Tab</kbd> and <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Tab</kbd> are working the way you expected.

Answer (score -1):

Best workaround I have found on mac/linux is to install a extension that sorts the tabs in MRU order*, so that ctrl+tab works the way you'd expect it to:

https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/tab-slider/nobaaibkcalggmjnjhnlmmcldllpogjp

* *last used tab is moved to all the way to the left*